# Cómo pasar imagenes cargada a un slideshow de bootstrap en el Flask?

Tags: python, bootstrap, flask

hala, alguien me prodria ayudar con esto, estoy probando  python + flask para el desarollo web, pero me a surgido esta duda, tengo un slideShow en bootstrap y me gustaria saber como puedo verificar que en la carpeta x se encuentren varias imagenes y estas se publiquen en el slide show, y si en el caso de ser 10 y magenes y luego se quieren agregar 11 verifique la cantidad y esta añadida se agregre al slide show.

python main

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory, render_template
import os
import os.path

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/test\src\static\img'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in ima and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            ima = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))
    return

@app.route('/show/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    filename = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/img' + filename
    return render_template('template.html', filename=filename)

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def send_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename)

if __name__ == ("__main__"):
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: lo que he logrado hasta ahora ha sido esto pero solo encuentra una imagen import os.path
import os


fin = os.path.isfile('img/1.jpg')

if fin == True:
   print("El archivo existe")
else:
    print("El archivo no existe")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el módulo `glob` para obtener una lista *rutas_imagenes* con las rutas de archivos ***.jpg** en tu carpeta *img*

```
rutas_imagenes = glob(os.path.join('img','*.jpg'))
```

...y luego usa esa lista para añadir las imágenes que quieres. No has puesto código `HTML` ni `python`, así que depende de ti como hacer uso de la lista, pero supongo que un `{%for%}{%endfor%}` en el código del `slideshow` seria un buen comienzo.

## **EDIT:1**

Sigues sin poner mucha más información. Tendrás que agregar el código de `glob` a la función que devuelva el template que corresponda al carrusel, y en el código `HTML` algo como esto:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for _, ruta in enumerate(rutas_imagenes)  %}
    <div class="carousel-item {% if _ == 0 %}active{% endif%}">
        <img src={{ ruta }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% block content %} {% endblock %}
```

El uso del condicional `if` dentro del `div.carousel-item` y del modulo `enumerate` en el for-loop es para dejar un solo elemento como `active` y el resto de las imágenes no.

Según como tengas establecidas las rutas de la carpeta `static` quizás necesites jugar con `../static/img` en el valor de `src` para que apunte a la direccion correcta si la ruta que apunta 'rutas_imagenes` es incompleta.

No puedes añadir código en los comentarios. Debes corregir tu pregunta y darle el formato adecuado con las guías de estilo.

A partir de aquí deberias de ser capaz de continuar por ti mismo. Si no, necesitas estudiar más la documentación y regresar con una duda mucho más concreta.

Un saludo,

Comment: Gracias; este es mi codigo  en html:
{% extends "layout.html" %} <!-- improtar desde termplate layaut-->

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/encarte2.jpg') }}"<!--En esta parte seria donde debo aplicar eso para que aparesca la imagen --> class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div> 

 {% block content %}

 {% endblock %}